# Solidworks: Why is the Projected Curve position different from the preview?

Tags: solidworks

Preview:
[image]

Projected curve: [image]

If anybody has any ideas that would be great. Also, the issue is not only a 'visual' issue, but also a functional issue. I am attempting to use the projected curve in a swept cut, but I get errors. Thanks!

Comment: What plane is the projection onto? Is it parallel to the plane being projected?

Comment: It is not parallel, the face I am projecting onto is at an angle from the plane being projected. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Yes. A projection is always perpendicular to the viewing plane.

Answer (score 1):

> Me: What plane is the projection onto? Is it parallel to the plane being projected?

> You: It is not parallel, the face I am projecting onto is at an angle from the plane being projected. Could this be the issue?

From Wikipedia:

> **Orthographic projection** is a means of representing three-dimensional objects in two dimensions. It is a form of parallel projection, in which all the projection lines are **orthogonal** (perpendicular) to the projection plane, resulting in every plane of the scene appearing in affine transformation on the viewing surface. [Orthographic projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection).

Yes. That's the problem.